# Matlab: Calculating the standard error of values in a spreadsheet

Tags: matlab

I generated the following spreadsheet:

[image]

As you can see I have two values in each column.

I would like to:

**1)** Get the standard deviation of these two values (in all columns simultaneously)

**2)** Acquire the standard error (in all columns simultaneously) by applying this equation: standard deviation/square root of 2 (or standard deviation / 1.41421356237)

In order to get a table looking like this (having one value per column)

[image]

Comment: Please try to do some additional research on these sorts of questions before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this

```
T = [451.7050 258.5121 -39.6087; 527.2373 410.6641 77.1401];
Res = std(T)/sqrt(size(T,1));
```